# Determining how many objects are eligible for GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection

There is a question in SCJP third chapter.
See the following code:

```
public class Sample_1 {


    Short story = 200;

    Sample_1 go(Sample_1 sample){
        sample = null;
        return sample;
    }

    public static void main(String a[]){
        Sample_1 sample1 =new  Sample_1();
        Sample_1 sample2 =new  Sample_1();
        Sample_1 sample3 = sample1.go(sample2);

        sample1 = null;

        //DO STUFF

    }

}
```

Question: How are many objects are eligible for GC @ line `//DO STUFF`?

options:
0
1
2
Compilation Fails
Its not possible to know
An exception is thrown at run time

Book says: the correct ansert is 2. It says that "only one Sample_1 object (sample1) is eligible for GC,but it has associated Short value with it.So there are two objects eligibe for GC"

Still not able to understand this answer. We are already nulling sample1 object. From my view there are no objects for GC.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution..
  here ... there are three objects sample1,sample2,sample3.

sample3 is null so dont need to GV it. I mean its not initialized throughout the program.
  sample2 is under use upto last statement.So JVM can not GV it.

And we are nulling sample1. So its added to GV queue.And sample1 itself has Short object.So there are   two objects ready for GV.

Thanks,Gunjan.

Answer (score 1):

Since sample1 is null, the memory allocated for sample1 and the Short variable it contained are eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

> Still not able to understand this answer. We are already nulling
>   sample1 object. From my view there are no objects for GC.

Setting a variable to null does not mean it is GC'ed, it means that it is eligable to be GC'ed.  You cannot programmatically control when the GC will run.